# Is composite index really necessary for a table with composite primary key?

Tags: sql

Let's say we have a table to store users' favourite pictures, with a composite primary key pair(UserId, PictureId). Books normally say in this case you need a composite index based on (UserId, PictureId), which normally appears in the WHERE clause as (UserId=103 AND PictureId=1234). But I think the dababase engine should be smart enough to use two individual indexes based on the two columns separately. Just get the set of row numbers from each of the index and find the ones that are present in both sets. That way, a composite index is not necessary.

So, in reality can database engines do that?

Comment: If you're using a composite PK, then all your FK need to contain **all** the columns of the PK - period. After all: if you use the two columns as your PK, only the **combination** of those two columns uniquely identifies a row - right? If not: then your PK is wrong - maybe you don't even need a composite PK - one of the columns alone will reliably and uniquely each row? Then use just that one single column as your PK.

Comment: @marc_s: This is a case of "many to many" relationship between tables, where you need a third table with composite primary key as a go-between.

Comment: OK but in that case - you need one index on `UserID` and a second, separate index on `PictureId` (to speed up the JOIN's to the other tables involved), and you possibly need a unique constraint on the `(UserID, PictureId)` pair to avoid duplicates. In this case, in my opinion, a *composite primary key* on both columns doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

There'd be no advantage to using the two separate single-column indexes; the engine would be better off doing a table scan.

The point of using an index is to make access faster.  If the engine used two indexes, it would have to sort at least one set of data from one of the indexes and merge the results from the two indexes. That would be a lot more work than reading just one composite index, especially since the composite index allows for an index-only scan.

Comment: What if you're trying to look-up a single image by ID (a plausible use case).  Then wouldn't the single-column index on the *picture id* be beneficial?

Comment: If you said were true, which I doubt, then whenever there is "AND" condition in a WHERE clause, all the indexes for single columns which appears in the WHERE clause would be useless. But I do agree there is no performance gains by using two single column indexes than a composite index key.

Comment: SQL Server has the ability to join two or more individual indexes and intersect them, just as if you were using a composite index, giving you the best benefits of single and composite indexes.http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2007/composite-indexes/

Answer (score 1):

Most database engines will *require* the composite index to *enforce* the primary key. As such, it's a "free" index that you're going to have anyway - why worry about it?

There may be some benefit (if the index is on `UserID,PictureID`) to adding a second index just on `PictureID`. Any query on just `UserID` will be able to use the composite index, whereas a query just using `PictureID` would be unable to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I think in the use case you describe, the composite index is not necessary.  That would be useful if you were doing a query on, say, a given set of user IDs plus a given set of picture IDs.  But when would you ever need that?  You'd be more likely to query all a user's pictures in a given date range, or lookup a specific picture by ID.  This would suggest an index structure of one composite *user id + date* index, and another *picture id* only index.

It always depends on the distribution of records in your database, and the types of queries you will be running most frequently.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe would be significantly more expensive than using composite index.

First a set of rows would need to be identified from the first index, then a set of rows from the second and finally the set-intersection performed between the two.

#### --- UPDATE ---

Note hat this is the price you would pay for **every** INSERT/UPDATE and every foreign key check, not just SELECT.

Also, there may be concurrency issues involved - depending on how the DBMS is implemented, enforcing uniqueness through a single unique composite index might require less/simpler locking than enforcing uniqueness through two non-unique, non-composite indexes.

And of course, if you intend to [cluster](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-organized-clustered-index) your table, the primary index will typically also be the clustering index, and contain all columns anyway, so there isn't much purpose in leaving anything out from the "sorting" portion of the index.

Comment: Describe to me why it would expensive? Checking through an index is not expensive at all because B tree is good for random access. Do you think reading through the table of contents of a book TWICE is as expensive as reading through a book?

Comment: @Aperture It would be 2 index range scans instead of one index seek. And the set-intersection also has some cost. And no I don't think that, nor did I say that. From the wording of my answer it's clear I was comparing it with the composite index and not table scan.

Comment: My friend, think about it, no matter how many B-tree indexes you search through, it is never going to be a fraction of the time needed to do a full table scan. Also the IMO the difference between using a clustered and non-clustered index to too small when compared to a full table scan of a million records. Just my thoughts.

Comment: @Aperture What are you talking about? Why are you even mentioning table scan?

Answer (score 0):

PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraints are *abstract*, theoretical concepts.

An INDEX is *practical* physical thing that lives in the real world.

In practice, indexes can be used to enforce PK or UNIQUE constraints. But other techniques could also be used (eg for a small domain: a bitmap)